# Conversation Plugin vs ActionFlow

Tags: struts2, struts2-actionflow-plugin

Can anyone detail the differences between the Struts2 Conversation plugin and ActionFlow plugin and when I should choose one or the other?

Regards

Comment: Conversation plugin is for handling data. ActionFlow is for creating wizards.

Comment: Sorry - but what is the difference? Surely wizards are also for collecting data over a series of forms as well?

Comment: @user497087 Don't worry, looks like the same thing but different implementation.

Comment: @user497087: They are totally different plugins for different purposes. Conversation plugin adds `conversation` scope to your application. ActionFlow plugin helps you create wizard from actions where holding data in some scope is just one of the features. With ActionFlow you can define sequences of actions (e.g. which action will be executed after the current action). With Conversation you can define which data will be put into `conversation` scope and when conversation will start and end.

Comment: @user497087: Have you understood the differences between this two plugins? Do you have any further questions?

Answer (score 1):

They are totally different plugins for different purposes. `Conversation` plugin adds `conversation` scope to your application. `ActionFlow` plugin helps you create wizard from actions where holding data in some scope is just one of the features. With `ActionFlow` you can define sequences of actions (i.e. which action will be executed after the current action). With `Conversation` you can define which data will be put into `conversation` scope and when conversation will start and end.

Use [ActionFlow](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/struts2-actionflow) plugin when you need to create a [wizard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_%28software%29).

Use [Conversation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/) plugin when you want to add [conversation scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html) to your application.